# Where can I view all my custom keybindings in bash?

Tags: bash, terminal

I like using tab for     `menu-complete`
(default is just `complete`), and I want to know what bash file stores this information. I want to know this so that I know where to look for to check if the keybindings have been changed from default, or if I want to port these changes to another comp.

Does setting a key binding like:
    bind `TAB:menu-complete`
roll over to every session? It's not saved in my .bashrc, so I don't really know where to find it.

Comment: You can set it in a `bash` configuration file (making it used only `bash`), or in `.inputrc` to make it available to anything using the Readline library.

Comment: unable to find .inputrc anywhere. I don't think I'm using the same system. Is that the file that contains all the keyboard bindings?

Comment: `.inputrc` is the default readline configuration file but it doesn't exist until you create it because the actual defaults are built in. If you want the *current* bindings try `bind -p` or `bind -P`?

Comment: So what you're saying is that if I wanted to bind a key, I'd have to bind it again every session unless I create a .inputrc? Otherwise it's not saved?

Comment: You mean to say .bashrc? That one seems to make more sense

Comment: @EtanReisner, hi, neither bind commands shows the custom bindings I have. I also dont have an .inputrc file. Is there another location where these could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keybindings are not persistent.

If you want to apply them to every session, you can put a `bind` command in your bash interactive startup file, but it is probably better to put the settings into your readline startup file (normally `~/.inputrc`, see the [bash manual chapter on readline initialization](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Readline-Init-File)). The readline initialization file can be shared between different applications, and has a syntax for conditionally setting bindings depending on application. Note that this file may not exist on your machine, since most people just use the defaults, which are hard-coded into the executable.

It is always a good idea to test a keybinding before you make it permanent. Otherwise, you may find that your bash shells are unusable.